# What is MS Word 2016 doing that eats so much data while passively open in the background? Updates disabled

Tags: microsoft-word, bandwidth, microsoft-office-2016

I can mostly only connect to the internet using metered connections, and use Glasswire to monitor how much data each of my applications eats. I also have **Office updates disabled** to prevent excessive data usage.

I've noticed that every time I have Word 2016 open, it uses surprisingly high amounts of data for no obvious reason - not vast amounts, but more than I can see any explanation for.

For example, in the last few hours today, when I've done nothing with Word but open one small file from a local drive and read it without making any edits, it's eaten 9 times as much data as my *email client*:

[image]

Word itself gives no indication or warning of why it's eating all this data, and Office 2016 is an application that is aware that my network is a "metered" connection. It can't be anything to do with checking Office 365 accounts (I'm on a Business subscription, in case that's relevant), because if it was I'd expect Excel to do the same, but Excel only eats kilobytes of data.

**Why would Word be eating tens of megabytes of data every few hours when not doing anything (just sitting with one document open in the background) and not updating itself (because updates are off)?**

---

Currently, because it seems excessive and there's no reason I can see, I'm using the firewall to block it.

Comment: Doesn't Glasswire tell you what IP Address/Website is been accessed? This might give you a clue what Word is doing.

Comment: @sgmoore Good call - I can click on the application, then "Hosts", and it gives me data usage per host. Unfortunately it's not hugely informative in this case - over 99% came from akamai.net, which is basically a mirror service. It could be almost literally anything.

Comment: Maybe something like Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) would show you more information, including the URL and what data is being transferred?